# How can you set a TextArea in JavaFX to allow only integers to be entered?

Tags: javafx, textarea

I am trying to create a TextArea in JavaFX which only accepts integer values? Can anyone give me advice as to how to implement this?

Comment: See linked question - should work similarly for `TextArea` as does for `TextField`.

Comment: Presumably in a `TextArea` you would want to allow newlines at least, and possibly whitespace in general, so you would need to modify the regex in that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`TextFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html):

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
// allow digits and whitespace:
Pattern allowedText = Pattern.compile("[0-9\\s]*");
TextFormatter formatter = new TextFormatter((TextFormatter.Change c) -> {
    if (allowedText.matcher(c.getText()).matches()) {
        return c ;
    } else {
        return null ;
    }
});
```